# The code works incorrect in CodeSignal. Not sure if it's my code defect

Tags: c++

The description could be somehow incorrect, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code.

I try to solve a problem in [CodeSignal](https://codesignal.com/). I wrote down the following snippet, but when it runs, I see the below result.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> rotateImage(std::vector<std::vector<int>> a) {
    int hsize = a.size() / 2;
    int row = 0;
    for (; row < hsize; ++row) {
        std::vector<int>& row_top = a[row];
        std::vector<int>& row_bottom = a[a.size() - row - 1];
        int row_width = a[row].size();
        for (int col = 0; col < row_width / 2; ++col) {
            int& cell_top_left = row_top[col];
            int& cell_top_right = row_top[row_top.size() - col - 1];
            int& cell_bottom_left = row_bottom[col];
            int& cell_bottom_right = row_bottom[row_bottom.size() - col - 1];

            // rotateCellsCW(cell_top_left, cell_top_right, cell_bottom_left, cell_bottom_right);
        }
        cout << "LOOP: " << row << " " << hsize << endl;
    }
}

╔═════════════════╦═══════════╗
║      Field      ║   Value   ║
╠═════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ Input           ║ a:        ║
║                 ║ [[1,2,3], ║
║                 ║  [4,5,6], ║
║                 ║  [7,8,9]] ║
║ Output          ║ undefined ║
║ Expected Output ║ [[7,4,1], ║
║                 ║  [8,5,2], ║
║                 ║  [9,6,3]] ║
║ Console Output  ║ LOOP: 0 1 ║
║                 ║ LOOP: 1 1 ║
║                 ║ LOOP: 2 1 ║
║                 ║ LOOP: 3 1 ║
║                 ║ LOOP: 4 1 ║
║                 ║ LOOP: 5 1 ║
║                 ║ LOOP: ... ║
╚═════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but in my opinion, it's a defect.

Comment: First of all you don't do any rotation at all. Secondly, you have some debug output that the system won't recognize and flag as invalid.

Comment: Hey man. I mean why is the loop (the first one) continues to run? Why the `row` reaches values like 5 if the value 4 is less than 1?

Comment: Is the code you show the actual code you run? Have you copy-pasted the correct code? Do you have a [mcve] that calls this function and which replicates the invalid behavior that we can try ourselves? And have you tried to step through the non-working code in a debugger to see what really happens?

Comment: I wrote all the necessary (and unnecessary) information that I have. I don't know even what compiler it uses.

Comment: With the code you show I [can't replicate](https://godbolt.org/z/CjuGLA) the looping problem (only changes made: Commented out unused variables, prefix `cout` and `endl` with `std::`, returning from the function, and a `main` function which calls the function).

Comment: For that reason I mentioned CodeSignal. You could simply check what it is before commenting.

Comment: Try commenting out everything but the output in the outer loop, so you have only `for (...) { cout << ...; }`. Is there still the same looping problem? Then your code is correct (with such minimal code it's hard to be incorrect, the more minimal the less chances or errors), and you should report it to the maintainers of that site. But if it does work then, the problem is most likely in your code, and you need to piece-wise add back your code until it stops working, then you know which part introduced the error and can concentrate on debugging that part.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for comments. I already figured out the problem. You can see the answer. It's quite illogical why that happened.

Comment: To be honest, that's just working around the symptom, not fixing the actual problem. Your loop, as shown, just shouldn't continue past `row == 0`. If the loop does then there's something very wrong that needs to be fixed. If the problem is in your code, then you will hopefully learn something and not have that problem again, but if the root problem is not in your code then it could be part of some bigger problem that needs to be solved, and your workaround doesn't really do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours trying to figure out what is wrong, I finally found out, that it's needed to return from function in order to make the loop to stop running. I don't think if it is logical, but anyway. That was the solution to the problem.